# Cython: for i from 1 <= i < N

Tags: python, for-loop, cython

I'm learning [Cython](http://www.cython.org) and came across this snippit of code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def mean(np.ndarray[np.double_t] input):

    cdef np.double_t cur
    # Py_ssize_t is numpy's index type
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = len(input)

    for i from 0 <= i < N:
        cur += input[i]

    return cur / N

a=np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.double)
```

Obviously, this returns the mean of *a* which is 2.5. My question is this:

Is the for loop a Python loop, Cython, or C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile it and see: the C code that Cython produces is nicely annotated.

```
  /* "cyexample.pyx":11
 *     cdef Py_ssize_t N = len(input)
 * 
 *     for i from 0 <= i < N:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *         cur += input[i]
 * 
 */
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_N;
  for (__pyx_v_i = 0; __pyx_v_i < __pyx_t_1; __pyx_v_i++) {
    /* "cyexample.pyx":12
 * 
 *     for i from 0 <= i < N:
 *         cur += input[i]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 * 
 *     return cur / N
 */
    __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_v_i;
    __pyx_t_3 = -1;
    if (__pyx_t_2 < 0) {
      __pyx_t_2 += __pyx_bshape_0_input;
      if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 < 0)) __pyx_t_3 = 0;
    } else if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 >= __pyx_bshape_0_input)) __pyx_t_3 = 0;
    if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 != -1)) {
      __Pyx_RaiseBufferIndexError(__pyx_t_3);
      {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 12; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
    }
    __pyx_v_cur = (__pyx_v_cur + (*__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(__pyx_t_5numpy_double_t *, __pyx_bstruct_input.buf, __pyx_t_2, __pyx_bstride_0_input)));
  }
```

And so the loop itself is successfully turned into C.  Note that these days Cython can handle range naturally, so the older "from 0 <= i < N" style isn't necessary.  The point of introducing the (non-Python) "for/from" syntax was to signify which loops should be C-ified.

Comment: I did some naive timeit tests and both loop structures appear to run in about the same amount of time with array size large. Can anyone confirm this? I'm just curious why the author of this particular snippit chose to use the older structure in modern code.

Comment: Back in the day, Cython wouldn't optimize `for i in range(10)`, so it would actually create a list of length 10 and iterate over it using Python call backs. Due to this, Pyrex/Cython introduced the for ... from ... syntax, which would boil down to C. I sometimes still use the older syntax because it is more clear that this code is optimized.

Answer (score 5):

`for..from` seems to be a Pyrex / Cython loop: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#integer-for-loops

Comment: Correct. It is a Pyrex form of for loop that Cython has kept for backwards compatibility